# JNDI Context Initialization error while migration from WAS to liberty

Tags: jms, jndi, open-liberty

The `WsnInitialContextFactory` class not found exception. Liberty does not support this class, then how can I remove `jndi.properties` default settings. This property file contain this class name for `InitialContext`.

**Properties:**

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory" 
CC_PROVIDER_URL = "iiop://localhost.svr.us.xxxxxxx.net:41516"
```

**InitialContext** *Lookup*:

```
   try {
        Hashtable params = new Hashtable();
        params.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ADProperties.WS_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        params.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ADProperties.AD_PROVIDER_URL);

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(params);
        try {
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + jndiName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogUtil.debugException("DBConnectionManager", "Exception in init: Resource reference DataSource lookup Error.", "init()", ex, "");
            try {
                ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/" + jndiName);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                LogUtil.debugException("DBConnectionManager", "Exception in init: Datasource lookup Error.", "init()", exp, "");
            }
        }
```

**Exception:**

```
[INFO] [err] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
[INFO] [err]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO] [err]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [err]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO] [err]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[INFO] [err]    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASInitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(WASInitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:57)
[INFO] [err]    at [internal classes]
[INFO] [err]    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
[INFO] [err]    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
[INFO] [err]    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
[INFO] [err]    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
```

Comment: You have to switch to default constructor `new InitialContext()` and as Alasdair wrote, make sure you dont have `jndi.properties` in your app or in classpath. This code is in client app?? You need to write more details how is your app constructed and how it is using this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Liberty does not support the WsnInitialContextFactory class. You can just do this (and it'll work in WebSphere traditional as well):

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(new Hashtable());
    try {
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + jndiName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogUtil.debugException("DBConnectionManager", "Exception in init: Resource reference DataSource lookup Error.", "init()", ex, "");
        try {
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/" + jndiName);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            LogUtil.debugException("DBConnectionManager", "Exception in init: Datasource lookup Error.", "init()", exp, "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Gas - Can you please look into this issue here.

Comment: Do you have a jndi.properties file on the classpath? Have system properties been set specifying the InitialContextFactory configuration?

Comment: I don't have the jndi.properties. But I have read the details that even though if you dont provide properties in initial context. It will get this class from jndi.properties.

Comment: Do you suggest any other alternative class for initial context factory?

Comment: You can just do new InitialContext() with no properties. That also works in WebSphere traditional.